# Extracting a component from an existing html page to external files

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, components

I have the following html/js existing working code that I want to extract in their own files and load them using require.js.

My goal is to componentize it to be able to use it elsewhere.

.html

```
...    
<ul data-bind="foreach: selectedExams">
        <li>
            <select data-bind="options: $parent.availableExams, optionsText: 'examTypeName', optionsValue:'examTypeId', value: examtype"></select>
            <select data-bind="options: exams,  optionsText: 'examName', optionsValue:'examId',value: exam, enable:exams().length"></select>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Remove</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>
...
```

.js

```
    var self = this;
...
    self.availableExams = [...];

    self.selectedExams = ko.observableArray([new selectedExam(self)]);
    self.add = function () {
        self.selectedExams.push(new selectedExam(self));
    };
    self.remove = function (exam) { self.selectedExams.remove(exam) }
...
```

It seemed very simple at first, but I am confused because the viewmodel seems to need a complete rewrite.

Because I want to experiment and see how it works, following the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html), I've created a separate .html file with exactly the required content show above.

And the following autonomous .js file:

```
function ExamControlViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.availableExams = [...];

    self.selectedExams = ko.observableArray([new selectedExam(self)]);
    self.add = function () {
        self.selectedExams.push(new selectedExam(self));
    };
    self.remove = function (exam) { self.selectedExams.remove(exam) }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ExamControlViewModel());
```

Next, I've removed the code from the original html/js files and added the following to the js file :

```
ko.components.register('exam-control', {
    viewModel: { require: 'exam-control-viewmodel' },
    template: { require: 'text!exam-control-view.html' }
})
```

It fails at runtime with the following error :

Script error for "text", needed by: text!exam-control-view.html_unnormalized2
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

Obviously I'm missing the point, This could not be that simple... Could it be ?

Any guidance appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

I followed @JotaBe excellent instuctions and ended up with the following :

.js file

```
define([],function() {
    function ExamControlViewModel()
    {
        var self = this;
        self.availableExams = [...];

        self.selectedExams = ko.observableArray([new selectedExam(self)]);
        self.add = function () {
            self.selectedExams.push(new selectedExam(self));
        };
        self.remove = function (exam) { self.selectedExams.remove(exam) }
    }
    return ExamControlViewModel;
});
```

html file:
=> At the beginning

```
...
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/knockout-3.4.0.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/knockout.validation.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/require.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='Scripts/text.js'></script>
...
```

=> The component code was replaced by (forgot to say that when asking the question)

```
<exam-control></exam-control>
```

Now at runtime, I have the following error:

*Mismatched anonymous define() module*

I'll update this thread again as I make progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do these things:

1. export your module constructor following the AMD pattern
2. include the `require.js` text plugin so that the templates can be loaded by require
3. configure require.js so that it can find your templates and scripts
4. register the component

#### 1. Export the viewmodel constructor

The AMD pattern to export the constructor looks like this:

```
define([/*dependencies*/],function() {
  // define the constructor you want to export
  function ExamControlViewModel() { ... }
  // export it
  return ExamControlViewModel;
});
```

This must be the only content of your `exam-control-viewmodel.js` file. You don't need to `applyBindings`: knockout will copy the template content and apply the binding when both the script and the template are loaded.

I suppose you have loaded `knockout` globally. If you've done so, keep the definition as explained. However, if you load `ko` and related stuff (like plugins) by using `require.js`, you should include it as a dependency, by making this change in your file:

```
define(['ko'],function(ko) {
```

Of course you need the right configuration paths to load knockout as `ko`. If not, you'll have to specify the whole file name (and path).

#### 2. Include the require.js text lugin

The `require.js` `text` plugin is available [here](https://github.com/requirejs/text), and here you can see the [related documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text). You can install it by copying it or using any of the available packages formats, like [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RequireJS.Text/) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs-text).

#### 3. Configure require.js

You have to configure require so that it can find the files, as [explained here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config). You must pay special attention to `baseUrl`.

#### 4. Register the component

The component registration is correct as you've done it. In particular `'text!exam-control-view.html'` instructs `require.js` to use the `text` plugin to load the template. The `.js` file must have the specified name.

Becasuse of the way that `require.js` and the plugin work, as you've done, the `.html` extension must be included, and the `.js` must be removed.

If you have specified the correct configuration, the files will be read from the specified `baseUrl`. If not, you'll have to modify it. If they're not loaded correctly, you can use the browser's console to find what the problem is.

Of course, `require.js`, and the related configuration must be loaded before you use the components.

Comment: Excellent guidance ! I have updated the question, I think I have a problem exporting the viewmodel constructor.

Comment: @omatrot Your question was long enough not to be read. And now that you find a new problem, instead of making a new question, you make your question even longer. You should only modify a question to include new relevant information, or to improve the wording. But please, don't make this kind of edition. Your new question could be this one which has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371918/mismatched-anonymous-define-module Looking at the browser's console can help you to determine whatthe problem is.

Comment: @omatrot Your constructor AMD module is correct. Please, try to require both your script and template without ko, i.e. using directly `require(['',''], function() {})` in a simple .html page that only includes require. Then include all your scripts one by one. How did you setup require.js? I can't see where you did it.

Comment: require.js was installed via Nuget

Comment: No, I didn't mean how you installed it, but how you specified the configuration (the baseUrl and so on). How did you configured it?

Comment: It was point 3. I recommend you creating an additional script file, which I usually call 'require.config.js' which must be loaded before `require.js` itself. When you load `require.js` it detects the existing configuration, and applies it. Please, see this: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100064/discussion-between-omatrot-and-jotabe).

Comment: I've used pattern number 5 to successfully to configure require.js. My component is successfully loaded in simple HTML page. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should include [text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) for `RequireJS`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546347/knockout-component-widget-template-requirejs-html/34241572#34241572) I have written a more detailed answer.